# Crm 2011 : Refresh associated Grid View

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Is there a way to refresh associated Grid View ? 
I have a Sales Order View on the Account Form, on this Form I have a button (New Order) that open a new Sales Order Form, in this form I do my Orders,
The question is : When I save on my Order Form I want to refresh my Order  associated View (in the Account Form) , but I don't know how to get the control name or how to access to it.
I tried many ways Like

```
  Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("Orders").refresh();
  document.getElementById("areaOrders").contentWindow.location.reload(true);
```

Thank's.

Answer (score 3):

To refresh a subgrid you can use

```
Xrm.Page.getControl('new_subgrid').refresh();
```

However in my experience it is very buggy (since RU12 anyway), so use with caution. You also need to check the type of the control you retrieve and ensure it is a grid or an error will be thrown.

However you have asked a slightly different question:

> When I save on my Order Form I want to refresh my Order associated View (in the Account Form)

Which I understand to mean you have an Order form opened from an Account form and want to refresh the subgrid on the Account form.

The easy answer is no, you cannot do this in a supported way.

It may be possible but it wouldn't pretty. You'd need to get a reference to the opening window, which may be available in

```
window.opener
```

I haven't tried and am not infront of a machine to try it. But I would advise against it, the alternative is a single click to manually refresh the subgrid; it isn't a bad alternative.

Comment: You are right, I have two Forms, Account Form wish have a subgrid of my Sales Order, and an Order Form opened from the Account Form. I have tried (window.opener) but it didn't works to, if it's not possible to do a refresh, how Microsoft did it when I add for example a new Contact or a new Account it does refresh the sub_Grid View . It must be a way to do this. Like you know , when you open a new Order Form you have a save Button that insert your data into SalesOrderBase and SalesOrderExtensionBase table, when you click on this button , the subgrid Associated View is automatically refreshed.

Comment: I changed that because I want to insert my custom data, so when I click on Save button I cancel the code what this button should do and I execute my code, since that the sub_grid does not refresh !

Answer (score 1):

This is a javascript function I wrote to force Subgrid loading if the form contained more than 4 subgrids.  I believe a recent rollup has made the purpose of the code obsolete, but it might be helpful for you to find your subgrids:

```
/*
By default, CRM only loads the first 4 subgrids on a form.  This will load
up all subgrids on the form, or only the number (over the default 4) if specified
*/
forceSubgridLoad: function (countOver4) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var links = $("a.ms-crm-List-LoadOnDemand");
        for (i = 0; i < links.length && (countOver4 == null || i < countOver4); i++) {
            links[i].click();
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: But is it possible to refresh a Sales Order associated view on Account Form from Sales Order Form ?

Comment: @wben So the view isn't on the main tab of the entity form?

Comment: Now, I have an Order form opened from an Account form, and my associated view in on the Account Form

Answer (score 1):

I have blogged about [auto-refreshing a sub-grid in Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://bruce.windram.co.za/?e=13).
The solution is an unsupported customization, and basically boils down to this:

```
document.getElementById("crmGrid").control.refresh();
```

Replacing "crmGrid" with the div id of the sub-grid that is to be refreshed.

As far as I know there is no supported way to do a refresh.