# Refresh view with javascript when a new entity is created

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

In dynamics CRM 2011, how do I refresh a view from another window?

This relates to a view for custom entities that are displayed in a grid. A user can click on one of the rows and edit that entity in a new window. They also have a ribbon button to "copy" the entity. When copy is selected a third window opens with an exact copy of the original.

After copying a record I'd like to refresh the original view so the new entity is shown there automatically.

Have attempted to use javascript below but doesn't work - is there another way?

```
opener.window.reload(true);
```

Comment: Could you please explain with some screenshots or skip the irrelevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refresh the grid as below:

```
Xrm.Page.getControl('new_subgrid').refresh();
```

Ref: [Crm 2011 : Refresh associated Grid View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612879/crm-2011-refresh-associated-grid-view)