# Refresh associated view list

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

In CRM 2011, is there a way to refresh an associate view for an associated entity via Javascript? I know you can refresh a subrgid that's been placed on the form of the parent entity. But I cannot figure out a way to refresh the child entities associated view (the list you see if you click on the child entities link in the left hand navigation of the parent entities form, e.g. Case > Child Cases).

I'm trying to do this from a custom ribbon button. I have that calling a Javascript function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crm 2011 : Refresh associated Grid View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612879/crm-2011-refresh-associated-grid-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this working.

Call `$find(gridname).Refresh();` to refresh the grid. Replacing gridname with the name of the grid which you can find using developer tools in your browser and looking for the the value in the gridid attribute.